# Counter example for Wronskian Concept .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I know the result that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the differential equation $$y’’+p(x)y’+Q(x)y=f(x)$$ then Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)=ce^{\int -p(x)dx}$ of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is given by Abels Theorem ($ P,Q $ and $f $ are continuous functions in some open interval I). So by Abels theorem Wronskian does not change sign because of constant $c$. Now I am searching counter example of differential equation for which coefficient functions are discontinuous so that Wronskian changes Sign i.e. Wronskian some time becomes positive and sometimes negative. Please provide some counter example. Thank you.

Comment: The standard example is the DE that has $x$ and $x|x|$ as solutions. The Wronskian of these two functions changes sign at the singular point $x=0$ of the DE.

Comment: @LostinSpace in all of your examples functions are not solutions of differential equation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you sir .... sir what is that differential equation. Please .

Comment: I think Cauchy Euler type

Comment: @LutzLehmann   if differential equation is of order two then problem is $x|x|$ is not twice differentiable .

Comment: The differential equation to two given solutions is $0=W[y_1,y_2,y]$. To satisfy additional conditions just increase the degree, like $y_1=x, y_2=x^2|x|$